# Operators from finite measure L_1 into some L1 with arbitrary measure

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $T$ be a bounded lineaer operator from $L_{1}(\mu,\mathcal{A})$ into $L_{1}(\nu,\mathcal{B})$, where $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure and $\nu$ is some measure. If the measure space $(\mu,\mathcal{A})$ is countably generated (hence $L_1(\mu, \mathcal{A})$ is separable), then the range of $T$ can be embedded into some separable sublattice $L_1(\tilde{\mu},\tilde{B})$ of $L_{1}(\nu,\mathcal{B})$. In the general case (if $(\mu,\mathcal{A})$ is **not** countably generated), is it true that the range can be embedded into some $L_1(\tilde{\mu},\tilde{B})$, where at least $\tilde{\mu}$ is $\sigma$-finite?